# Eclipse PDE: How to add java project's classpath to a plug-in's classpath?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, project, classpath, osgi

People,

I already searched a lot but I'm not finding my answer..

I did a eclipse plugin that writes junit test cases from source code.

By now, I'm starting to use reflection in my code, but the plugin can't find the classes in the java project being tested!

Is there a way to use the selected project classpath in my plug-in? How??

I've seen many questions like mine out there, but with no answers. Please someone help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could perhaps try to write programmatically a launch configuration that includes in the classpath both your plugin source code and the project source code.

By doing this way you should provide a valid entry point to your application.

this [article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Java-launch/launching-java.html) explains how

Otherwise you could try to base your plugin on eclipse jdt using the Abstract Syntax Tree that jdt provides to generate the unit tests.

ref [eclipsepedia](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_extend_the_JDT%3F)